# sshd.exe is not presen in script path

Tags: windows, powershell, server, sshd

I have the problem that a script executed correctly on one server (2016 / PS5.1) but fails on another (2008 / PS2). The Path should be alright because it already worked. I'm quite sure it is a PS Version Problem, however I'm do not have enough experience nor knowledge to figure this one out...

The Error:

```
sshd.exe is not present in script path
Bei C:\Admin\LANAgentTransfer\OpenSSH-Win64\install-sshd.ps1:14 Zeichen:10
+     throw <<<<  "sshd.exe is not present in script path"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sshd.exe is not present in script path:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : sshd.exe is not present in script path
```

[Relevant](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) install-sshd.ps1:

```
    # @manojampalam - authored initial script
    # @friism - Fixed issue with invalid SDDL on Set-Acl
    # @manojampalam - removed ntrights.exe dependency
    # @bingbing8 - removed secedit.exe dependency

    $scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $scriptdir = Split-Path $scriptpath

    $sshdpath = Join-Path $scriptdir "sshd.exe"
    $sshagentpath = Join-Path $scriptdir "ssh-agent.exe"
    $etwman = Join-Path $scriptdir "openssh-events.man"

    if (-not (Test-Path $sshdpath)) {
        throw "sshd.exe is not present in script path"
    }
```

SCRIPT:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force

Set Variables
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("XY", "XY") 
$url = "ftp://XY/OpenSSH-Win64/OpenSSH-Win64/"
$localPath = "C:\XY\XY\OpenSSH-Win64"

function DownloadFtpDirectory($url, $credentials, $localPath)
{
        $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
        $listRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
        $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials

        $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

        $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
        $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
        $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)
        while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
            $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
        }
        $listReader.Dispose()
        $listStream.Dispose()
        $listResponse.Dispose()

        foreach ($line in $lines)
        {
            $tokens = $line.Split(" ", 9, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
            $name = $tokens[8]
            $permissions = $tokens[0]

            $localFilePath = Join-Path $localPath $name
            $fileUrl = ($url + $name)

            if ($permissions[0] -eq 'd')
            {
                if (!(Test-Path $localFilePath -PathType container))
                {
                    Write-Host "Creating directory $localFilePath"
                    New-Item $localFilePath -Type directory | Out-Null
                }

                DownloadFtpDirectory ($fileUrl + "/") $credentials $localFilePath
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Downloading $fileUrl to $localFilePath"

                $downloadRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
                $downloadRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
                $downloadRequest.Credentials = $credentials

                $downloadResponse = $downloadRequest.GetResponse()
                $sourceStream = $downloadResponse.GetResponseStream()
                $targetStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($localFilePath)
                $buffer = New-Object byte[] 10240
                while (($read = $sourceStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
                {
                    $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $read);
                }
                $targetStream.Dispose()
                $sourceStream.Dispose()
                $downloadResponse.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }

IF (Test-Path C:\XY\XY\OpenSSH-Win64) {
    ECHO "FOLDER ALREADY EXISTS"
}

    else{
    #Function to Download all Files from a Directory
    md "C:\XY\XY\OpenSSH-Win64"
}

IF (Test-Path C:\XY\XY\OpenSSH-Win64\scp.exe) {
    ECHO "FILES ALREADY EXIST"
}

else {
  DownloadFtpDirectory $url $credentials "C:\XY\XY\OpenSSH-Win64"
}

#Install SSH via integrated ps1
C:\XY\XY\OpenSSH-Win64\install-sshd.ps1

#Set Service to start automatic and start service
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service -Name sshd

ECHO "SCRIPT SUCCESFUL"

Set-ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
```

FOLDER CONTENT:

[image]

I'm open for critique!

Comment: @Swisspick - sshd.exe is expected in the same location as `install-sshd.ps1`. From your screenshot, the `sshd.exe` is missing (among others).

Comment: Yes that is the answer! Wow, I really didn't see that. After deleting the folder and its contents, I started the FTP transfer again, all files were downloaded successfully, even sshd.exe. Thank you very much @LievenKeersmaekers !

Answer (score 0):

The FTP transfer was incomplete so files were missing, after redoing the transfer everything went fine.

Thanks @LievenKeersmaek for pointing it out!